# Compare two objects based on criteria

Tags: c#, string, linq

I need to compare two `List<object>` but during comparison for properties having "string" value **I don't want case sensitive comparison**.

I have a class:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string name { get;set; }
}
```

I have 2 lists `List<User> olduser` and `List<User> newuser`. I need to compare both lists but while comparing I should ignore case sensitivity of "name" field and get values in `olduser` not part of values in `newuser`.

```
List<User> obsoleteUsers = olduser.Except(newuser).ToList();
```

I need to add a condition that while comparing two lists, please ignore the case for "name" field.

Comment: Does `Except` take a comparer as a parameter?

Comment: Do you want this comparison to **always** be used when comparing `User` objects for equality? Or just in this one **specific** scenario (comparing these lists)?

Comment: Should the comparison also take into account the ID or just the name? One of the answers below checks both while the other only compares the name

Comment: @mjwills yes always

Comment: @pinkfloydx33  only the name is required

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
class UserNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public UserNameComparer(StringComparer comparer)
    {
        if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));
        this.Comparer = comparer;
    }

    public StringComparer Comparer { get; }

    public bool Equals(User x, User y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return true;
        return Comparer.Equals(x.name, y.name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(User obj)
    {
        return Comparer.GetHashCode(obj?.name);
    }
}
```

You use it in `Except`(or other LINQ methods):

```
List<User> obsoleteUsers = olduser
    .Except(newuser, new UserNameComparer(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

On this way you can implement multiple comparers for different requirements without changing the original class and the way it identifies duplicates(for example by the `ID`-property).

Note that `Except`(and other set based methods like `Distinct`) use `GetHashCode` to fast-check if an object equals another. That's why your class should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`(always together) to support being used in a set based collection(like `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`). Otherwise you will use the version from `System.Object` that just compares references and not properties.

Comment: There is a typo in `if (Comparer == null)` it should be `if (comparer == null)`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to compare for equality with your own rules, let's implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods:

```
  class User : IEquatable<User> {
    // Dangerous practice: Id (and name) usually should be readonly:
    // we can put instance into, say, dictionary and then change Id loosing the instance 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(User other) {
      if (null == other)
        return false;

      return  
        Id == other.Id && 
        string.Equals(name, other.name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as User);

    public override int GetHashCode() => Id;
  }
```

Then you can put `Except` as usual

Comment: Probably important to note that `GetHashCode` is using a mutable property and that modifying `Id` while the object is inside a set/dictionary could cause it to get "lost"